# Switched from rsyslog to syslog-ng, but its not starting up

Tags: linux, kali-linux, syslog-ng

I wanted to switch logging from `rsyslog` to `syslog-ng`, but after configuration and startup, it faield to start up.

This is the log file I am getting, but I cant find any clues there what is wrong:

```
rrr-hp:~# systemctl status syslog-ng.service
● syslog-ng.service - System Logger Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/syslog-ng.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-03-22 12:51:35 CET; 4min 52s ago
       Docs: man:syslog-ng(8)
    Process: 448232 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/syslog-ng -F $SYSLOGNG_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 448232 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Starting up... (Mon Mar 22 12:51:35 2021"

Mar 22 12:51:35 rrr-hp systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Mar 22 12:51:35 rrr-hp systemd[1]: Stopped System Logger Daemon.
Mar 22 12:51:35 rrr-hp systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 22 12:51:35 rrr-hp systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 22 12:51:35 rrr-hp systemd[1]: Failed to start System Logger Daemon.
rrr-hp:~#
```

There is also `journalctl -xe` output, but that is not any clearer for me:

```
rrr-hp:~# journalctl -xe
Mar 22 12:41:37 rrr-hp syslog-ng[447444]: contact: https://lists.balabit.hu/mailman/listinfo/syslog-ng
Mar 22 12:41:37 rrr-hp systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit syslog-ng.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Mar 22 12:41:37 rrr-hp systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ The unit syslog-ng.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 22 12:41:37 rrr-hp systemd[1]: Failed to start System Logger Daemon.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit syslog-ng.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit syslog-ng.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 7765 and the job result is failed.
Mar 22 12:41:38 rrr-hp systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
░░ Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit syslog-ng.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Mar 22 12:41:38 rrr-hp systemd[1]: Stopped System Logger Daemon.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit syslog-ng.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit syslog-ng.service has finished.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 7865 and the job result is done.
Mar 22 12:41:38 rrr-hp systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 22 12:41:38 rrr-hp systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ The unit syslog-ng.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 22 12:41:38 rrr-hp systemd[1]: Failed to start System Logger Daemon.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit syslog-ng.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit syslog-ng.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 7865 and the job result is failed.
rrr-hp:~#
```

I have been trying to switch between `unix-dgram` / `unix-socket` / `unix-stream` based on: [syslog-ng service not starting with systemd but command works fine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202044/syslog-ng-service-not-starting-with-systemd-but-command-works-fine) but neither of them worked.

My linux version is:

```
rrr-hp:~# cat /etc/debian_version
kali-rolling
rrr-hp:~#
```

Could anybody give me hints, what can be wrong, or where to search for more clues?

Comment: Does `journalctl -u syslog-ng` provide better information?

Comment: Try to start `syslog-ng` manually (from the terminal,  not from the `.service` file) and look at the error messages.